# Remove pagination from WooCommerce product categories on admin edit navigation menus

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, menus, pagination

[image]

I am creating a WooCommerce store with a very big nested menu structure. Is there a way to stop my product categories from paginating?

I need them to all show in one big list so that I can use Ctrl+F to find them quickly. That "Search" next to "View All" isn't working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec your code worked! Thank you very much. However the pagination is still showing but the code is doing what I needed done.

Comment: Happy it wordked, as I didn't really test my code (what I mostly never do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on *"[Remove Pagination in Appearance -> Menus -> Categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299178/remove-pagination-in-appearance-menus-categories/300174#300174)"* answer thread for WordPress categories, you will adapt the answer code to WooCommerce Product Categories.

The taxonomy of WooCommerce Product category is `product_cat`.

Is also better to target admin nav menus only.

Try the following *(untested)*:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'admin_nav_menu_show_all_product_categories', 10, 2);
function admin_nav_menu_show_all_product_categories( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'nav-menus.php' === $pagenow && reset($taxonomies) === 'product_cat' ) {
        $args['number'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('terms_clauses', 'change_product_cat_terms_clauses', 10, 3 );
function change_product_cat_terms_clauses( $clauses, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'nav-menus.php' === $pagenow && reset($taxonomies) === 'product_cat' ) {
        $clauses['limits'] = '';
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **LoicTheAztec**, it works for me. Pagination destroys my product category hierarchy and displays in the wrong positions. But after your code snippet, pagination still displays, so Ive added this:

```
function admin_product_cat_terms_nopagination($hook_suffix) {
    if ( $hook_suffix == 'nav-menus.php' ) {
        echo '<style>#tabs-panel-product_cat-all .add-menu-item-pagelinks{ display:none }</style>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_product_cat_terms_nopagination');
```